# xml file in browser using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to display xml file in broswer: for example: http://www.mysite.com/myfile.xml
I know there is code snippet on net:

```
 App::import('Xml');
        $file = "filename.xml";
        $parsed_xml =& new XML($file);
        $parsed_xml = Set::reverse($parsed_xml);
```

but this one display an array of the xml file. How could i display it simple xml file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://book.cakephp.org/view/483/Creating-an-RSS-feed-with-the-RssHelper